# Defining shortcuts for QGIS plugins?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, shortcuts

I'm writing a plugin using QGIS. I want to associate a shortcut to a procedure called "test".

The code i am using is the following :

```
self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Q), self.iface.mainWindow())
self.shortcut.setContext(Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
self.shortcut.activated.connect(self.test)
```

For unknown reasons it seems to work **erratically**:

When I define a new key sequence (let's say "A") it is ok. I change the code, reload the plugin (with **plugin reloader** tool) the shortcut is working.
Then the shortcut seems to get unresponsive (I don't find the reason why..)

I choose another key sequence (let's say "Z"), it is working.

When I try to switch it **back** to a previous setting (back to "A" for example) it is not working either ...

It seems that only new key sequence choices are working (for a while only ...)

What could I be doing wrong?

Is it an issue that could occur only during design mode of the plug-in?

Comment: Or maybe is it just something like a scope issue ? ...